# What triggered the slang term "epic fail"?

Tags: slang, phrase-usage

***Epic fail*** is defined as a spectacularly embarrassing or humorous mistake, humiliating situation, etc., that is subject to ridicule and given a greatly exaggerated importance.(Dictionary.com)

The expression is very popular but also quite recent. According to [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=epic%20fail&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) its earliest usages date back to around 2006 or so but it has dramatically increased since then.

What triggered its popularity? TV Shows, political commenters or what?

Comment: I don’t have the rigor to turn this into a proper answer but it was an internet catchphrase people used on forums like 4chan.

Comment: Doesn't provide the catalyst, but see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/wordplay/epic-fail-a-success-story): _The History of 'Epic Fail'_

Comment: Not the origin, but boosted in popularity by "viral" internet sensations and the launch of [Fail Blog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail_Blog) in 2008.

Comment: It's really epic failure, not fail. But like everything in American speech, it is reduced as much as possible. There's nothing new about the idea at all.

Comment: @Lambie Come on, now.  That's just silly.  What's the American version of 'cuppa'?

Comment: @JimmyJames Cup of tea

Comment: @Lambie The shift to maximal terseness is not an American thing, it’s an online lifestyle thing (I hesitate to use ‘internet’ here because it predates what most people mean when they use that term, going at least as far back as BBS services and Usenet), though texting is what really caused it to take off.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Way before the Internet, the Aussies did this kind of thing. I think it was already prevalent in email.

Answer (score 19):

This is internet slang, pure and simple, and you can't find out about that through normal channels, such as OED, your parents, or any hidebound source that never "pwned" or got "pwned" on a video game.

According to the [Know Your Meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/fail-epic-fail) website, it all started based on an old video game:

> The earliest documented usage of the term “FAIL” can be traced to a Japanese 16-bit scrolling shooter game, "Blazing Star," which was released on February 26th, 1998.[5] The game was often mocked for its grammatically incorrect “game over” message that reads: “YOU FAIL IT! YOUR SKILL IS NOT ENOUGH- SEE YOU NEXT TIME- BYE BYE" (shown below).
> As seen with the *All Your Base are Belong to Us* meme, the combination of a retro video game narrative and *Engrish* translation proves itself to be a powerful source of *lulz*.

I recall hearing and seeing the term "Epic Fail" in the early part of the century, mainly in MMORPG "Massive Multiplayer Online Role-Playing Game" contexts. More from the same article:

> While the exact origin of “FAIL,” as an interjection, remains unknown, the earliest appearance of “FAIL” on slang repository Urban Dictionary dates back to July 22nd, 2003.

And now we do have a standard source weighing in only a handful of years later:

> On August 9th, 2009, the New York Times, in almost verbatim to Know Your Meme Episode, reported on the FAIL phenomenon. They wrote:
>
> > This punchy stand-alone fail most likely originated as a shortened form of “You fail” or, more fully, “You fail it,” the taunting “game over” message in the late-’90s Japanese video game Blazing Star, notorious for its fractured English.

The term "epic" attached to it is merely an intensifier, which tagged along later. If you look at the Urban Dictionary site, the [first listing](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=epic%20fail) it gives for "Epic Fail" is from September 15, 2006. One a year later is more illustrative of the inanity:

> **epic fail** The highest form of fail known to man. Reaching this level of fail means only one thing:
>
> > You must die, or the world will fail itself due to such an extreme level of failage.
> >
> > > **Noob**: OMG I gotz teh myspaces n mah yootoobs rool n sutf n u sux cuz u has no myscapes!
> > > **Me**: Epic fail.

Apologies for the non-standard citations, but as I mentioned above, these are so far the only sources that keep track of the wild and wacky internet on anything like a current basis.

Comment: Fail as in "you failed" is well-attested since at least the 70s and doesn't require importation from another culture. It was the original "sad-trombone."  The meme site often takes credit for things it ought not. It would not often be written down because it was a spoken interjection.

Comment: @Yorik: Thanks. However, "Fail" used alone as an interjection (or including the intensifier "epic") is not the same as "You failed" (perfectly ordinary and not-slangy-at-all English). There is a certain blocky abruptness to the former that didn't really come to life until about the time stated in my answer. I, for one, first became aware of the trope in the early aughts of this century, and I was certainly around to notice in the 1970s..

Comment: disagree completely, and I am speaking from direct experience here. It gained more notice because it was written down in chat contexts which encourage a less formal word choice, but the exact use (sans *epic*) was quite common in conversation. Obviously derived from PASS/FAIL written on test papers.

Comment: OK, and as noted I'm speaking from direct experience as well. We'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @Yorik Is your 70s assertion related to surfing/skateboarding culture by any chance?  I'm not sure why but I have this feeling that it came out of that culture.

Comment: *Epic fail* precedes the internet by several decades. We were using it in ultimate frisbee in the mid 1970's.

Comment: *pwn* is in the *OED*. Just sayin’.

Comment: First thing that came to mind was [Fail Blog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail_Blog), which I believe made the word "fail" a bit more popular on the internet, but according to Wikipedia it started at around 2008. That is a bit later than some of the examples given here, so maybe there is a much better source.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I never said it wasn't in there now. But it certainly wasn't when the term was current.

Comment: @Robusto, do you have a blog I can follow or some network where I can join you?

Answer (score 4):

**epic** is first recorded in writing by OED, and in this sense, in 1983

> **2b.** colloquial (originally and chiefly U.S.). **Particularly impressive or remarkable; excellent, outstanding.**
>
> 1983 When University of Florida linguistics professor David Pharies
> asked 350 sophomores for samples of college slang, here's what he
> found... ‘Killer’ is a compliment, along with ‘mint, awesome, prime,
> epic, golden, [etc.]’ *USA Today 29 September d1/5*
>
> 1985 The world's greatest surfers challenging the world's most epic
> waves. *Surfing May 66*

The OED continues

> **Fail** n. = **failure** n. obsolete except in phrase "without fail".

It is first recorded in

> 1297 Þer wyþoute **fayle**, At Eccestre strong enou hii smyte an batayle. *Robert of Gloucester's Chronicle (1724) 245*

and last in

> 1678 There might be never any Fail of Generations. *R. Cudworth, translation of Plutarch in True Intellectual System of Universe i. iii. 128*

This meaning has now been resurrected in the modern "an epic fail" sense = an outstanding failure.

The earliest I can trace "Epic Fail" is "Big Book of Epic Fail" By Aaron Williams published in 2007 but obviously, the phrase, as a spoken term, existed before some time before this.

> What triggered its popularity?

Schadenfreude and the internet.

Comment: NYT article "How Fail Went From Verb to Interjection" has a source tracing "fail" as an interjection probably to a poorly translated video game from the late 1990's.

Comment: Noun use of "fail" also exists in the context of student assessment results. While "fail" may be regarded as a short form of "failing mark" or similar, in practice it is used as a noun in this context.

Comment: @Peter Can we really assign a part of speech to the labels "pass" and "fail" on an assignment or class grade? They're essentially just shorthand for "you passed" and "you failed".